# Getting No suitable driver found for jdbc//mysql://localhost:3306/nishadagar while connecting mySQL to java in eclipse

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect mysql to java in eclipse on Ubuntu machine but I am facing issue.
I have already installed mysql-connector-java-5.1.47

Please find below my code:

```
Package com.dataproviders;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class DbData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Connection conn=null;
        String dburl="jdbc//mysql://localhost:3306/nishadagar";
        //String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, "root", "root");
        System.out.println("success");
}
```

Please find below Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc//mysql://localhost:3306/nishadagar
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.dataproviders.DbData.main(DbData.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection URL appears to be syntactically incorrect.
The connection URL should be :

```
             String dburl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nishadagar";
```

The double forward slashes have been replaced with a colon. Please refer the official documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html).